# Showing that there is just one maximal solution to a differential equation defined for all the reals.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a problem about ordinary differential equations.

I am given this ODE:  $y' = y^2 + (\sin(xy))^2$.

I am asked to prove that the null function is the only maximal solution defined for all the reals to this ODE.

These are a few things I have thought about:

- Since the solution for any IVP has to be unique (Picard's Theorem) and Y = 0 is a solution, all other solutions must have constant sign because they cannot intersect with that solution.
- The solutions are increasing functions because their derivative is positive.

However, I do not manage to prove that the rest of maximal solutions are not defined for all reals. By the way, I do not think I have to solve the equation to answer this problem. I think it is more of a theory exercise.

If anyone could give me a hint it would be really helpful.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that the right hand side is bigger than $y^2$. That means that the solution issued at some $x_0$ of your equation is larger (while it exists) than the solution to $y'=y^2$ with the same initial data, for $x>x_0$ and smaller than the solution to $y'=y^2$ for $x<x_0$. But the solutions with $y(0)\neq 0$ of the latter equation are easily seen to blow up (you can integrate explicitly, separating the variables)  at some $x>0$ if $y(0)>0$ and at some $x<0$ if $y(0)<0$. Therefore your solutions also blow up at some finite $x$ unless, of course, $y(0)=0$.